# how do I grep through a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, grep

Looking for a nifty helper function/method for grepping through all defined tables, columns, stored procedures, etc, for a MySql database.

I had something similar for SQL Server.

Comment: Shazam! http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database:

```
select * from columns WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tablename%' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%columnname%'
```

More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Ok, it doesn't completely answer your question but you should be able to put it together how you want from here.

Answer (score 42):

`mysqldump --compact --skip-extended-insert -u root -proot mydb | grep "interesting string"`

Comment: The compact and skip-extended-insert options are really valuable. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou - this is the one I really wanted

Comment: Simple and to the point. Thanks for this. It can be even shorter if you are on a sandbox and don't have a root password (by omitting the -u  and -p parts).

Answer (score 2):

or simple, MySQL Workbench -> Database -> Search Table Data...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and thanks for your answer. Does your method allow the writing of the data to a file? The OP asked how to grep the information, and I am not sure that your answer will allow for a grep search.

Answer (score 1):

Common Resource Grep (crgrep) searches for table/column name and data matches and supports MySQL.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep/

Also searches other hard to search resources like content buried in archives. I developed crgrep as an opensource tool.

Comment: Craig - do you have a connection to that project? If so, you should state it in your answer. I say this because you've just posted a virtually identical answer to two other old questions ...

Comment: Yes, I'm the author. I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stored procedure here (http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=232) for MySQL which will create a table for storing output, then loop through information_schema database's COLUMNS table to obtain all database's table and column names. Next execute a count() query on database.table for each column with appropriate search string in where condition. If count() > 0, that perticular column has the search term, so it will insert that triplet (database name, table name, column name) into a table. Last Select * from table to view respective database table and column names having the search term.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL Grep

I wrote small python utility for this:

Find table.field and how many times found (-c)

```
$ sqlgrep mysql://localhost/libro --like '%beer%' -c
libro.title: 18 rows matched
libro.titolo: 2 rows matched
libro.autore: 15 rows matched
...
```

Find and print fields (without -c)

```
$ sqlgrep mysql://localhost/libro --like '%beer%' 
libro(id=225) title: 'THE ART OF GUNFOUNDING. The Casting of Bronze Cannon in the late 18th Century. - De Beer Carel. - Jean Boudriot Publications, - 1991'
libro(id=7154) title: 'MICROBIOLOGIA DEL PETROLIO - Beerstecher Ernest - Feltrinelli, Saggi scientifici n. 3 - 1963 - Milano'
...
```

And can print all fields for each matching record (with `--all` option). (No example for brevity)

### Details

SQL Grep uses SQLAlchemy, so it supports all databases (if proper driver for SQLAlchemy is installed). SQL Grep searches in all tables/fields but NOT searches in stored procedures

### Install

Either with pip or pipx. Example:

```
pipx install sqlgrep[mysql]
```

pipx install is recommended if your system supports it and if your database is MariaDB or PostgreSQL. For other databases, install it via pip and install proper driver

Repository (and full README): https://github.com/yaroslaff/sqlgrep